# Using complex model in MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have:
1)

```
public class Model
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public SubModel SubModel { get; set; }
}
```

2)

```
public SubModel
{
    public String Title { get; set; }
}
```

3) Model-typed ModelViewUserControl
4) SubModel-typed SubModelViewUserControl
5) Page

I need:
Show on the Page **2 TextBoxes**: for **Model.Name** and **Model.SubModel.Title**.

I do:
1) In Page:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("ModelViewUserControl", Model); %>
```

2) In ModelViewUserControl:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name) %>
<% Html.RenderPartial("SubModelViewUserControl", Model.SubModel); %>
```

3) In SubModelViewUserControl:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title) %>
```

Result is
In Controller's method I have Model.Name == "Bla" but Model.SubModel == null.
Of course, I use Html.BeginForm().

HTML:

`<input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" />`
`<input id="Title" name="Title" type="text" value="" />`

Comment: The fact is in Controller's action (after entering some information in the TextBoxes and submiting) Model.Name == "Name" but Model.SubModel == null

Comment: you can edit your post.  When you do, add a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `RenderPartial` I would recommend you using [editor templates](http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2010/04/26/mvc-2-templates/) which will make your life easier:

In the main View:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%= Html.EditorForModel() %>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

Editor template for the model (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Model.ascx`):

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) %>
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.SubModel) %>
```

Editor template for the SubModel (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/SubModel.ascx`):

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your two action methods are using the **SAME** data type for the model.

Your view can display the textbox fields like this:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name) %>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubModel.Title) %>
```

If you need more help, post your action methods and your view.

Comment: Action method has signature (Model model) and it successfully gets the Name property of the Model, but it don't get Model.SubModel.Title

Comment: What does your HTML source code look like for these two fields? Does it have the entire path in the name attribute? I assume you're using Html.TextBoxFor(), go head and post a snippet of your HTML source.

Comment: <input> tags has names (and the same Ids): "Name" and "Title".
I think, right variant is "Name" and "SubModel.Title" ...

Answer (score 0):

Take the following with lots of salt. I'm still working through this stuff.

This isn't the easiest way to figure this out, but a debug method I use for these things is to change the action parameter to a FormCollection. Then I do:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string key in fc.Keys)
        {
            sb.Append("Key: " + key + " Value: " + fc[key]);
        }
```

And inspect the value of sb in debug. This is probably a bad time waster, but it's how I've stumbled through this so far.

The issue you're having is the model binding. The Title input element needs to be named something like [ObjectType]_[PropertyName]. I don't know why the Html.TextBoxFor is not handling that.